# Reduce default spacing in column widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to put some text widgets inside a column, but there is this additional padding that I want to get rid of. Is there any "clean" way to do it? I could probably use `Stack` and specify the padding for every element in my case, but it is not a scalable solution.

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Text('why'),
    Text('so'),
    Text('stretched'),
  ],
),
```

[image: default column widget spacing]

Comment: Have you tried `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`?

Comment: What font-family are you using? Probably it's due to the font-family you are using. Different fonts have different properties.

Comment: `MainAxisSize.min` gives no effect, but indeed I am using a custom font, so this could be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have few solutions here:

1/. Add `height` for `style` of `Text` widget, `height` is double, default is `1.0` You can reduce it to `0.8` or `0.6` or any number as you want.

2/. Add `SizedBox` wrap your `Text` widget and set `height` for this `SizedBox` as you want.

Comment: Wrapping text with `SizedBox` is very scalable as well, but chaning height of the text style seems to be the good idea and solves the problem, thanks!

Comment: @radoslawik If your text is long and have multiple line, should use solution 1.
If you make sure `maxLines` of text is 1 so you can use Solution 2.

Comment: I would tent to avoid the sized box, because if I decide to globally change the font size I have to change each sized box height as well